# Which would be more suitable lens in terms of utility, weight, price: 18-135 or 18-55 + 55-200?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, zoom, kit-lens, superzoom

Is it better to invest in one 18-135mm lens or have a standard 18-55mm lens and another 55-250mm lens for occasional need?

Comment: You may also find some useful answers at [What is a good two lens “starter kit”?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4316/what-is-a-good-two-lens-starter-kit), and, actually, [Getting ready to buy an entry-level dSLR — should I skip the kit lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/getting-ready-to-buy-an-entry-level-dslr-should-i-skip-the-kit-lens), which asks about the 18-135mm vs the 18-55mm.

Comment: 18-135 then after next purcahse a 90-300mm  your all set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better to upgrade Canon 18-55mm IS kit lens to the 18-200mm, or complement with 55-250mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/is-it-better-to-upgrade-canon-18-55mm-is-kit-lens-to-the-18-200mm-or-complement)

Answer (score 7):

Things to consider 18-135mm:

- You dont need 135-250mm range.
- You dont like to change lens frequently.
- You want slightly better image quality within consumer grade.
- You want to carry only one lens with you.

Things to consider 18-55mm and 55-250mm:

- You dont mind changing lens often.
- You want the 135-250mm focal range.
- You dont mind the slightly less contrast produced by the 55-250mm.
- You dont mind carrying around multiple lenses with you.

Personally I think, if you want an all in one solution, you should get the 18-200mm, or if you prefer image quality, get the 15-85mm.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a bit of difference in the focal length range covered by a 18-135mm vs a total range of 18-250mm between two lenses.

**Its really a bit of apples and oranges comparison.**

If you need the longer focal length, go for the longer setup.  If you just need 18-135 range, get that one.  Quality wise, they're all consumer zoom lenses and probably about the same.

Answer (score 1):

With my previous (Pentax) camera I have had the 2 kit lens combo (18-55, 55-200) With my latest (Canon) I have the 18-135 and I am not thrilled with this lens. I've done some prior research and was expecting more in terms of image quality. I also didn't think I would miss the extra reach but I do. Thank god I also purchased the prime Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM otherwise my Canon experience would have been a sour one. I find the 18-135 so mediocre in terms of image quility, bokeh, etc. (I feels pretty good though) I only use it when I really have to, the prime lens is also the primary lens the moment.

What I should have done was just to get the body (or buy a cheaper older body) and get a pair of decent lenses instead of the one kit. @ShuttterBug has already suggested the 15-85mm which suppose to be very good for its class. Personally I would go with the Canon EF 17-40mm f/4.0 L USM, Canon EF 70-200mm f/4.0 L USM and 50mm f/1.4 USM combo.
However to answer your question; given only those 2 choices I would personally go with the 2 lenses rather then the 18-135.