# Which lenses are best for a beginner using a Canon EOS 100D?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, dslr

I have bought a new Canon EOS 100D camera along with the 18-55 lens, but I want one good lens for both wide-angle and zoom. This is my first SLR trying to learn more and more about the functions and settings. However, I am not satisfied with the 18-55 lens. Can anyone suggest a good lens for my EOS 100D?

Comment: Could you amend your question in order to explain *why* you're not satisfied with the 18-55 lens? What problem are you trying to solve where you're being held back by the lens?

Comment: Some previous questions in this area: [1](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/what-is-a-good-general-purpose-lens-for-canon), [2](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13994/which-would-be-more-suitable-lens-in-terms-of-utility-weight-price-18-135-or), [3](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/cannon-eos-550d-which-lens-should-i-purchase), [4](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24454/best-general-lens-for-canon-crop).

Comment: It seems kind of harsh, but honestly until you can attempt to articulate exactly why your current equipment is not good enough, buying equipment is pointless. No disrespect intended, just a bit of harsh love :)

Comment: A lens that goes from wide angle all the way through telephoto will either cost quite a bit or won't be substantially better in quality than your 18-55.  Your best bet is probably to get a decent telephoto and then upgrade your standard zoom range later, but it depends on what you want to do and what your main complaints are currently.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend working with what you have until you understand what you needs really are  and what you are looking for. The more you shoot the more you realize what you are missing. You may also start out with a cheaper entry level lens to see if it fits your need, after that upgrade to a quality lens. Finally, I would say don't purchase a bunch of lenses right away, get used to a focal length / lens and use your feet. In the future you will have a good idea in your mind about what to reach for in the bag once you get a feeling for focal length relationships.